# Different of React Native Android and React Native IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

i'm new in mobile development
I wasn't never using MacOS before, and now i'm trying to build a crossplatform mobile app using React Native
The android mobile app is already built and run normally
But for now i'm trying to develop the app into ios mobile app use MacOS inside VMWare
And i have some question for it

1. Can i instantly copy my project which was built at windows OS(Android) to MacOS then run it?
2. Do i need to do extra things if i i can only copy my project from Windows OS to MacOS?
3. What is cd ios && pod install and what time should i run this script?
4. Why windows can't be used for developing ios app?
5. Can i connect my VMWare MacOS directly to my iPhone directly using WiFi?

Sorry i'm still a newbie and please apologize me if i have an unnecessary questions

Comment: `Why windows can't be used for developing ios app?`  Easy answer,  (Money).  Same reason Safari these days is one of the worst browsers out there, even Edge makes Safari look like IE6..

Comment: If you created this app using cli instead of expo see this page https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup and select MacOS target IOS. It walks you through setting up your environment, which you'll need to do to use cocoapods.  This is what pod install in your 3rd question is referring to. You need to run pod install after installing dependencies.